# Mocking location on map for iOS UI Tests?

Tags: ios, mocking, xcuitest, testautomationfx

anyone out there tried mocking location on map for iOS UI Tests programmatically (not using edit scheme > allow location simulation) please?

Comment: Are you not aware of  GPX file?

Answer (score 0):

Create a protocol and mock location manager

```swift
import CoreLocation

protocol LocationManager: class {
    var location: CLLocation? { get }
}

final class MockCLLocationManager: LocationManager {
    var location: CLLocation? {
        return CLLocation(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(exactly: 52.51657052665494)!,
                          longitude: CLLocationDegrees(exactly: 13.381044881575008)!)
    }
}

extension CLLocationManager: LocationManager { }
```

Then in your map view controller:

```swift
let locationManager: LocationManager = MockCLLocationManager()
```

I can't get the map view to display the blue user location indicator this way though.